# Accessing username on a custom user provider under symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

After some struggles I was able to implement a Custom User Provider in Symfony, however it isn't working as expected and I am having difficulties spotting where I've gone wrong.

This is my setup:

I created a CustomUserProvider class like so:

```
<?php
namespace XXX\AccountsBundle\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

use XXX\AccountsBundle\Entity\Accounts;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{

    protected $user;

    public function __contsruct (UserInterface $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    function loadUserByUsername($username) {
        $user = Accounts::find(array('email'=>$username));
        if(empty($user)){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('Could not find user. Sorry!');
        }
        $this->user = $user;
        return $user;
    }

    function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
        return $user;
    }

    function supportsClass($class) {
        return $class === 'XXX\AccountsBundle\Entity\Accounts';
    }
}
```

I registered services like so:

```
parameters:
    xxx_userentity.class:  XXX\AccountsBundle\Entity\Accounts
    xxx_userprovider.class: XXX\AccountsBundle\Security\User\CustomUserProvider

services:
    userproviderentity:
        class: %xxx_userentity.class%
    userproviderclass:
        class: %xxx_userprovider.class%
        arguments:    ['@userproviderentity']
```

And I created the provider like so:

```
providers:
    main:
      id: userproviderclass
```

The issue I have is that when I try to login, the $username variable in the loadUserByUsername function seems to be coming up empty and thus I can't implement the logic I need here (which is why I created a custom user provider in the first place).

I can confirm the function is in fact executing because I can force an exception on it that wouldn't work if it wasn't being executed, so I know the code is executing but I am not sure why the variable is empty when someone logs in.

The original (working) setup (without the custom user provider) simply uses this provider setup:

```
providers:
    main:
      entity:
            class: XXX\AccountsBundle\Entity\Accounts
            property: email
```

And this does work.  My guess is that I need to somehow specify the property: email in my provider but I am not 100% clear on how exactly I should be doing that.

I appreciate any directions!